# android google maps, locationListener is null

Tags: android, google-maps

I have the method `onLocationChanged` which is getting called successfully, however

```
if (mListener != null) {
```

it never gets passed that line as mListener is always null.

I am supposed to be setting mListener with this line:

```
@Override
public void activate(OnLocationChangedListener onLocationChangedListener) {
  mListener = onLocationChangedListener;
}
```

However that method appears to never be called.

So, how do I call the method `activate`?

Comment: and your question is...?

Comment: how do I call the method activate?

Comment: `whateverIsYourObject.activate(new OnLocationChangedListener ());`